# how to delete the annoying data in the csv file

Tags: python

i want to delete some string("Description" "This is a simulation") in my csv file, and also i want to delete some"=" in the data and  ", " at the end of the data. the file looks like the following

```
"time","student","items"

="09:00:00","Tim","apple",

="09:00:10","Jason","orange",

"09:10:10","Emily","grape",

"09:22:10","Ivy","kiwi",

"Description"

"This is a simulation"
```

i have tried .pop(). it didn't work

```
ff= []

import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:

    for row in csv.DictReader(f):

        row.replace(',','')

        ff.append(row)
```

i want to get like this:

```
"time","student","items"

"09:00:00","Tim","apple"

"09:00:10","Jason","orange"

"09:10:10","Emily","grape"

"09:22:10","Ivy","kiwi"
```

Comment: If `=` appears only before and/or after rows, you may leverage [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) method to clear that, then leverage `str.split` method by comma `,` to see if each row results in the same number of elements as the header row (if not, delete or do not include).

Comment: not a solution but a (dirty) heuristic is that your 'good' rows after the header line have a colon in them. Adding a line `if ':' not in row: continue` skips ones without a colon.

Comment: Also while `csv` module is powerful, it offers a bit less flexibility than a simple row-by-row string reading from the file, especially when you need to perform string operations to do the clean up job. So rather just `for row in f` and do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to read the file as raw text file rather than csv so that it will be easier for you to perform string manipulation with it.

**Edit:** I assume that `tmp` is the path to the CSV file and the `<list data>` is a list of dictionary generated by `csv.DictReader`. Then you can write the `convert(tmp)` by performing 2 main steps. One is to reformatted the file and it to a temporary file and the other is to read the temporary file into a list of dictionary data using `csv.DictReader`. After you're done reading the data, the temporary file will be deleted using the `os` module:

```
import csv
import os

def convert(tmp):
    new_lines = []
    temp_file = tmp + '.tmp'
    with open(tmp) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            # remove new line characters
            line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')

            # delete string
            line = line.replace('=', '').replace('"Description"', '').replace('"This is a simulation"', '')

            # don't add empty string
            if line.strip() == '':
                continue

            # remove last line commas
            if line[-1] == ',':
                line = line[:-1]

            new_lines.append(line)

    # write formatted data to temporary csv file
    with open(temp_file, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write('\n'.join(new_lines))

    # get list data
    ff = None
    with open(temp_file) as f:
        ff = list(csv.DictReader(f))

    # delete temporary file
    os.remove(temp_file)

    return ff

print convert('./file.csv')
```

Comment: how can i  use a function like  this   def convert(tmp):

                                        retrun <list data>

Comment: @9898 I've updated my answer to use the `convert(tmp)` function that returns a list of dictionary data of each row.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Mostly leveraging built-in `str` methods, with an assumption that the first row is always a valid header row.

```
ff = []

with open('file.csv') as f:

    for row in f:
        # strip empty lines, and head/tail = ,
        line = row.strip().strip('=').strip(',')

        # skip empty lines
        if not line:
            continue

        # assume first row is always a valid header row
        # split by comma to see if it matches header row
        if not len(ff) or (len(line.split(',')) == len(ff[0].split(','))):
            ff.append(line)
```